# Password is correct but "Invalid password" when I log in

Tags: linux-mint, login, xfce, i3

I am running Linux Mint Tessa 19.1 with both XFCE and i3 windows manager installed. I do not need to log in on startup but when I log out, I can't log in back again with my password in any of the windows manager.

I don't understand because the password works in the Terminal for any sudo command. I tried to change it but still, I can't log in with the new password either.

It does not come from the keyboard layout because the result is the same when I try to log in with the virtual keyboard.

I should also probably say that on the login screen XFCE is appears as (Default) although the computer always launches i3 on startup.

I entered the Terminal, logged in and launched `loginctl list-sessions`and I get this:

```
SESSION    UID    USER       SEAT    TTY
     c2    112    lightdm    seat0  
      4   1000    cassepipe  seat0   tty3
```

Any idea about what is going on ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: after you log out what is the output of `loginctl list-sessions` as root? I had same issue with xfce before as it didn't actually logged me out and I couldn't login to existing session. if implemented, try pressing alt+prt scr+k at login screen and check if it works afterwards.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a Prt Scr key on my late 2007 Macbook and Idk how to perform such a combination on the virtaql keyboard. I updated my question with the result of loginctl.

Comment: sorry, but it does not look like the same issue, so it is probably about something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem's solution was very simple. It said "Default" because I tried to login with the "Default" user name and not my user name. I just had to click on my name.

Why and when the Default user was created or its purpose, I have no idea about.